# Triggering CloudWatch log alarm every minute in case there is a new warning log entry

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, cloudwatch-alarms

I am able to send an email as soon as an `WARNING` level log entry is detected by CloudWatch which is fine so far. However, the problem is I get email **only once** and never again even though my app produces more and more `WARNING` log entries. Pure guess but I think I am not getting any emails due to the status remains in "In alarm" state. My aim is to get a new email after detecting a new `WARNING` log entry within last 1 minute. How can I modify this code to make it work please?

```js
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  name = "my-lambda-topic"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "subscription" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.topic.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "test@example.com"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter" "filter" {
  name = "my-lambda-filter"

  pattern        = "{$.level = WARNING}"
  log_group_name = "/aws/lambda/my"

  metric_transformation {
    name      = "my-lambda-warnings"
    namespace = "my-lambda"
    value     = "1"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "alarm" {
  alarm_name          = "my-lambda-alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  threshold           = 0
  evaluation_periods  = 1
  datapoints_to_alarm = 1
  statistic           = "Sum"
  period              = "60"
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.topic.arn]
  metric_name         = aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter.filter.metric_transformation[0].name
  namespace           = aws_cloudwatch_log_metric_filter.filter.metric_transformation[0].namespace
}
```